# Proving |f(z)| is constant on the boundary of a connected compact subset implies f has a zero or is a constant function

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a problem with an exercise regarding an application of the open mapping theorem.

> Let $U$ be a domain and $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$. Let $K \subset U$  be a connected compact set with non-empty-interior, such that $|f(z)|$ is constant along $\partial K$. Show that $f$ either has a zero in int($K$) or is constant.

I tried to solve this by contradiction. Suppose that the claim is false. Then $f$ has no zeros in int($K$) and is not constant. Because $K$ is compact it is bounded. If I can show that $K$ is open then $K$ is a domain and I can conclude that $|f|$  attains its maximum and minimum on $\partial K$. Because $f$ is constant on $\partial K$ it follows that $f$ is constant on the whole of $K$. This implies that $f(K)$ lies in the interior of a circle. Because $K$ is a domain and $f$ is holomorphic and not constant it follows from the open mapping theorem that $f(K)$ is a domain and therefore open in $\mathbb{C}$. But the interior of the circle containing $f(K)$ is empty so we get a contradiction.

The issue is that this argument rests on the idea that $K$ is a domain. In order for this to be true I have to show that $K$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$. Unfortunately I don’t see how to prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited** Assume that $f$ has no $0$ inside $Int(K)$.

*Case 1:* $f$ has a zero on $\partial K$. Then $|f|=0$ on partial $K$, and hence, by the maximum modolus principle applied to $Int(K)$ you get $0$ is the maximum of $|f|$.

*Case 2:* $f$ has no zero on $\partial K$. Then $|f|$ and $\frac{1}{|f|}$ are bounded on $K$.

Now, by the maximum modulus principle applied to $f$ and $\frac{1}{f}$ on $Int(K)$ both of these functions attain the maximum of the absolute value on $\partial K$. It is easy to conclude from here that $|f|$ is constant on $U$, from where it follows that $f$ is constant.

Comment: In fact, I have already done this with respect to $K$. But in order to do this for the whole domain $U$ I need the domain $U$ to be bounded which the exercise unfortunately does not say anything about .

Comment: @Polymorph Apply the Maximum modulus principle on Int(K). You know that $f$ attains the absolute max and min on $K$ by compactness, and by applying the maimum modulus principle to Int(K) you get that max/min are NOT in the interior.

Comment: @Polymorph Does the edit make the proof clear?

Comment: Yes. I did not think of the fact that int($K$) is open. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $A$ of points in $U$ where the function is locally constant (in other words $w \in A$ means that there is a small disc around $w$ and contained in $U$ on which $f$ is constant); by definition $A$ is open and it is easy to show that $A$ is relatively closed in $U$ ($w_n \in A, w_n \to w, w \in U$ take the Taylor series of $f$ which is convergent on some disc $D_w$ around $w$, $D_w \cap A$ non-empty by hypothesis, hence the Taylor series is constant etc).

In particular, since $U$ is a domain either $A$ empty or $A=U$ which implies $f$ constant since ovbiously $f'=0$ on $A$ (hence then on $U$) by definition

The above is true for any domain $U$ and any holomorphic $f$.

In this particular problem, if $K$ has non-empty interior so the problem is not vacuous and if $f$ doesn;t have a zero in the interior of $K$, it follows by maximum modulus that $f$ is constant there, so in particular the set $A$ above is non-empty, hence $f$ is constant on $U$ and we are done!